# Android - Fragment interaction using Anonymous class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity A which contain 7 fragment. For communication between fragment to activity and fragment to fragment, My activity explictly declare Fagment interface of all the 7 fragment.
The Syntax is like

```
class A extends Activity implements B.onInteraction, C.onInteraction, D.OnInteration .... {
}
```

This becomes long and i don't like explicity declaring it in on top of activity.
The other solution i can think of is define a method `setOnInteractionListener()` in each fragment and pass anonymous class to it like.

```
class B extends Fragment {
   public void setOnFragmentInteractionListener(OnFragmentInteraction listener) {
   }
}
```

By this way i don't need to override `onAttach()` of fragment and i don't need to explicty declare fragment interface on top.

My Question is: Is this a good way of doing things? What are the cons of using anonymous class here. Is there any better approach to do this or i should stick to explictly declaring interface while creating activity.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand the question cause I'm a beginner. In my oppinion can create an interface for all your fragments:

```
  public interface ActivityListener {
        void onCall(Fragment fragment);
    }
```

your activity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityListener {
      @Override
        public void onCall(Fragment fragment) {
            switch (fragment.getTag()) {
                case YOUR_TAG:
                    Log.d("listener", "called");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

in your fragment use onAttach() method to get the interface.

Comment: I dont want to write interface implementation with class name declaration. I am looking for an another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use EventBus (especially https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus, someone prefer http://square.github.io/otto/) to communicate between Fragments and Activity.

You need to register (and unregister) the listener (activity, for example, or another fragment) and create a method with `onEvent(<CustomEventclass> event);`

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this); //and unregister
```

And just post the event from the fragment like

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(<CustomEventClass> instance);
```

Making BaseFragment and pass the listener is also a normal way. This is just a developer choice.